# "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial" no Android 6 Marshmallow (API 23)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permission

Estou tentando registar um broadcastreceiver para que eu possa verificar um novo sms que possa chegar no dispositivo.

Estou obtendo um erro somente no android marshmallow no seguinte trecho de código do meu fragment:

```
    public static final String BROADCAST = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    .
    .
    .
    Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);//erro nessa linha
```

Erro:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED from pid=10506, uid=10064
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A partir da versão 6.0 (nível API 23), as permissões consideradas "perigosas"([Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html?hl=pt-br#perm-groups)) passam a ser validadas durante a execução do aplicativo e não ao instalar. Isto não invalida que elas não tenham de ser declaradas no *AndroidManifest.xml*.

As aplicações com ***targetApi 23+*** que requerem *Dangerous permissions* , para correr em dispositivos Android 6.0 ou superior, terão de se ajustar a esta nova abordagem.

Sempre que a aplicação executar uma operação que necessite de uma permissão deste tipo ela tem de verificar se a tem antes de executá-la.

Essa verificação é feita chamando o método [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                                                        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
```

Se a aplicação tem a permissão é retornado `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` caso contrário retorna `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`

Se a aplicação não tem a permissão é necessário pedi-la utilizando o método [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions%28android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int%29):

```
private final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 1;
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                                  PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);
```

Será então aberto um *dialog* a solicitar a permissão ao usuário.
O *dialog* é mostrado de forma assíncrona, sendo o método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` chamado quando o usuário responder.

Esse método deverá ser implementado de forma a tratar a resposta:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS: {
            // Se o pedido foi cancelado o array está vazio.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permissão foi concedida
                // pode fazer o que pretende

            } else {

                // permissão foi negada

            }
            return;
        }

        // outros 'case' se tiver outras permissões para verificar
    }
}
```

Para informação mais detalhada ver a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).

Comment: +1 ótima explicação!

Comment: Valeu ramaral eu estava lendo a documentação depois de ter postado a pergunta. Nesse link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions existem exemplos da google de como fazer. (deixando o link caso alguém ache útil)

Comment: Senhor, o diálogo é aberto automaticamente ou tem que fazer algum XML para isso?

Comment: É aberto automaticamente. Não precisa de me chamar de "Senhor":)

Comment: Ah eu não conseguir kk mais deixa pra lá meu app ta bom assim :)