# Método tirar foto direto do aplicativo só funciona em alguns celulares

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou com um problema no meu apk que permite que o usuário tire uma foto direto da aplicação, porem, em alguns celulares dão erro e fecha o app. Aqui está meu manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.diego.tecnologiadanet">

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="APP">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="APP">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_car"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Pode adicionar o erro que aparece no logcat?

Comment: Mano eu nao to emulando direto no cel, eu gerei o apk e algumas pessoas que estao usando o apk estao relatando esse problema.

Comment: Sem o detalhe do erro, apenas com seu manifesto, fica bem difícil te ajudar a encontrar o problema!

Comment: Difícil sem log de erro, use o Google Analytics para te ajudar com isso, toda exceção você pode reportar para ele. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=pt-br#configurao-do-projeto

Comment: Poste o código java. Qual a versão do Android dos dispositivos em que dá erro?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro em SMS BroadCastReceiver no android 6 marshmallow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120859/erro-em-sms-broadcastreceiver-no-android-6-marshmallow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem a descrição do erro fica bem difícil de entender o problema e sugerir uma solução, mas mesmo assim, vamos lá.

O que imagino que esteja acontecendo, visto que é apenas em alguns celulares, é que esses *celulares* estão rodando a versão do Android Marshmallow e não habilitaram a permissão de usar a câmera direto do App.

Isso acontece porque nessa versão do Android foi introduzida uma nova forma de controle de permissões e de como essas permissões são requisitadas ao usuário. Para o seu App funcionar como esperado, você precisa adaptá-lo à essa nova forma de gerenciar e pedir permissão.

Sugiro dar uma olhada [neste artigo do site oficial do Android para desenvolvedores](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html) e também essa matéria do [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-advantage-new-app-permissions-marshmallow)

Comment: Você está "chutando" uma resposta que, mesmo estando a premissa certa, não responde há pergunta(apenas um link). Repare que eu já tinha questionado o AP sobre a versão do Android.

Comment: @ramaral, na verdade só cheguei a essa conclusão porque tive problemas com esse tipo de permissão hoje pela manhã. Curiosamente, o caso era bem parecido. Sendo assim, não é bem um chute e sim baseado no cenário que ele descreveu. Principalmente porque a permissão necessária para usar a câmera está lá, mas ainda não sabemos se o App está preparado para esse tipo de "_permicionamento_".

Comment: Também pensei que problema fosse esse(daí o meu comentário perguntando), mas pode ser outro. O meu comentário à sua resposta resulta principalmente de a solução ser apresentada apenas com um link, o resto poderia ter sido dito em um comentário :).

Comment: Boa @ramaral ;)
Valeu a dica, vou me atentar mais a esses detalhes antes de postar uma resposta.

Comment: Uilque estive lendo sobre isso já.. E estou achando que seja este o problema. O celular e da versão marsh.. E em outros celulares com versões anteriores funcionam. Amanhã vou aplicar este meio de permissao. Obgdo pela ajuda

Comment: Carlos, isso ocorre porque nas versões anteriores ao *M*, o usuário já dá todas as permissões na instalação. :)