# Como fazer download de arquivos da WebView no SDCard caso esteja disponível

Tags: java, android

O App é um navegador simples que funciona como WebView.
Esse código faz que os arquivos seja baixado em uma pasta personalizada e funciona perfeitamente.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                                                    long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Nome da Pasta", filename);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
                intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Baixando", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

> O problema é que estão indo para a memoria do celular. Caso o celular tenha um SDCard inserido, como faço para que os arquivos sejam baixados diretamente no SDCard?

Comment: Isso é para rodar em que versão do Android(versão minima)?

Comment: Está rodando no 2.3... SDK minimo 9...

Comment: Qual a razão para ter de ser no SDCard?

Comment: Porque a maioria dos celulares tem pouca memória interna.

Comment: Tem a certeza que está a gravar na interna? Qual é o modelo do dispositivo que testou?

Comment: Sim tenho! Testei no moto G2 e G3 e no LG-E410F

Comment: Você está a usar `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` que, como o nome indica seria memória externa. O problema é que os dispositivos mais recentes podem ter mais de um tipo de memória externa. Além do SDCard, podem ter alguma interna(fixa) considerada com externa. Como nunca usei o *DownloadManager* não sei dizer se é esse o problema. Agora não tenho tempo, amanhã darei uma resposta para você testar.

Comment: Pode ser! Aguardo a resposta do senhor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está a usar `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` que, como o nome indica seria memória externa.
O problema pode estar no facto dos dispositivos mais recentes poderem ter [mais de um tipo de memória externa](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/traditional.html#multiple-external-storage-devices). Além do SDCard, podem ter alguma interna(fixa) considerada como externa.

O facto do minSdk ser 9 limita um pouco a forma de obter, com garantia, o *path* para o SDCard, por isso não garanto que o método seguinte funcione em todos os casos.<sup>(*)</sup>

```
public Uri getSDCardPathIfAvailable(){

    //Se o "primary external path" é um SDCard retorna-o
    if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getExternalFilesDir(null));
    }
    //Ler todos os "external paths"(não garanto se Android < 19)
    File[] externalDirs =  ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        for(File externalDir : externalDirs){
            if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(externalDir)){
                return Uri.fromFile(externalDir);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Não podendo fazer melhor, talvez, com sorte, o segundo seja o SDCard
    else if(externalDirs.length > 1 && externalDirs[1] != null){
        return Uri.fromFile(externalDirs[1]);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Coloque esse método na sua classe e substitua a linha

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Nome da Pasta", filename);
```

por

```
Uri uri = getSDCardPathIfAvailable();
if(uri != null){
    request.setDestinationUri(uri.buildUpon().appendPath(filename).build());
}else{
    //Não foi encontrado um SDCard(mas pode existir)
}
```

<sup>(*)</sup><sub>Samsung Galaxy Tab2(4.1.2), que tem mais de uma "memória externa"(fixa + SDCard), `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs()` retornou apenas a fixa. No Samsung Galaxy Tab3(4.4.2) retornou as duas.

Se os métodos `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs()` e `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(File externalDir)` fizerem o que é dito na documentação o método funcionará na versão 21 ou superior.</sub>

Comment: Testado no moto g3, quase funcionou: O problema foi que salvou no local errado la no sdcard, exemplo: **"sdcard/Android/nome.do.pacote/files/"** foi assim. Já nos android inferior a 5.1 parece não funciona mesmo.

Comment: Esse é o local certo, é aquele que é atribuído pelo android para a sua aplicação(repare na parte `.../nome.do.pacote/...`).

Comment: Não tem como por na raiz do SD Card?

Comment: O problema está em saber o nome da "raiz", ele pode variar de acordo com a API level/marca/modelo. Pense no caso em que um utilizador muda para outro dispositivo e quer continuar a usar a sua aplicação com o mesmo sdcard, ele deixará de ter acesso aos antigos downloads(pelo menos a aplicação irá).

Comment: Entendi. Vou considerar sua resposta, pode Ajudar outros que deseja assim. Mas desse jeito não compensa para a minha aplicação! Você já me ajudou muito e sou gratoa você! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se tiver mais alguma dúvida coloque uma nova pergunta, eu tentarei ajudar.

Comment: Você acha que é difícil fazer aquele negócio de conceder permissão do Android 6.0? (pra mim que sou iniciante)

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541)