# Problemas com câmera: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação que utiliza a câmera de um dispositivo. Porém, sempre que tento usar o `Camera.open()` ele dá uma exceção `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`. Estou procurando entender melhor este erro, porém é minha primeira aplicação que uso uma câmera. Segue o código:

Código do manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Código java:

```java
package br.com.camera;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.util.Date;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera camera = null;
    private int camId = 1;
    @InjectView(R.id.surfaceView)
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_take_photo)
    FloatingActionButton btn_take_photo;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_camera);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        //Instalamos uma surfaceHolder.Callback então nós notificamos quando o underlying surface é criado e destroido.
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        //Confirguração precaria, ,as requer um android versão rioritaria 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraImage();
            }
        });
        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                File file_image = getDirc();
                if(!file_image.exists() && !file_image.mkdirs()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Não pode criar diretorio para salvar imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String photofile =  "Cam_demo" + date + ".jpeg";
                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photofile;
                File picFile = new File(file_name);
                try{
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                    outputStream.close();

                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                }catch (IOException ex){

                }finally {

                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Imagem salvou... ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                refreshCamera();
                refreshGallery(picFile);
            }
        };
    }

    public void refreshCamera(){
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
            //Preview surface não existe
            return;
        }
        //Para preview antes de fazer as mudanças
        try{
            camera.stopPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        //Coloca no preview tamanho e faz alguma mudança de tamanho, rotação ou reformata as mudanças aqui,
        // inicia o preview com novas configurações.
        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void refreshGallery(File file){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private File getDirc(){
        File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        return new File(dics,"Camera_demo");
    }

    public void cameraImage(){
        //Tira a foto
        camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //Abre a câmera
        try{
            camera = Camera.open();

            Camera.Parameters parameters;
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            parameters.setPictureSize(352,288);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        }catch (RuntimeException ex){
            Log.e("ERRO",ex.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ocorreu um erro com a câmera! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        try{
            //O SurfaceView tem sido criado, agora comunica-se com a câmera para desenhar o Preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //para preview w reinicia camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

**01/08/2016**

Acabei de passar por uma situação muito estranha, meu aparelho é o **LENOVO VIBE A7010** e o `Camera.open()` sempre da a `Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to câmera service`, decidi pegar outro aparelho, um **Moto G primeira geração** e olhe o que aconteceu, o aplicativo funcionou perfeitamente, não sei qual o problema do **Lenovo a7010**, mas ultimamente estou tendo muita dor de cabeça com ele quando se trata de desenvolvimento, passei um tempo tentando fazer com ele funcione no Android Studio.

Comment: Ao invés de adicionar respostas que não respondem a pergunta, clique no [link de editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/143531/edit). Caso contrário, isso daqui acabará virando uma bagunça.

Comment: Tente abrir sua câmera normalmente no aparelho, clicando no ícone da câmera. Provavelmente não vai estar abrindo, esse é um bug do Android. Reiniciar o dispositivo resolve.

Comment: @VictorStafusa você tem razão, passou despercebido por mim.

Comment: Qual a versão do android que você testou? Android M?

Comment: Isso mesmo, a versão 6.0

Comment: Se o erro apenas ocorre na versão 6 ou superior, o problema pode ser de falta de permissões. Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541)

Comment: O problema era permissão do Android M, muito obrigado @ramaral irei colocar a minha solução....

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema com ajuda do nosso colega Ramaral, era simples, as permissões do Android 6.0 são diferentes de suas versões anteriores, porém, ainda é necessário declarar no manifest, segue o link que me ajudou e o código: [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120859/erro-em-sms-broadcastreceiver-no-android-6-marshmallow/120879#120879)

Código:

```
//...

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    permissoesAndroidM();

    //...

}

private void permissoesAndroidM(){
    if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

        }
    }
}

    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Abre a câmera
                openCamera();

            } else {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void openCamera(){
    try {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int x = size.x;
        int y = size.y;
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        int aux = display.getRotation();
        switch (aux) {
            case 0:
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                parameters.setRotation(90);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(y, x);
                parameters.setPictureSize(y, x);
                orientation = 90;
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Orientação: " + orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                parameters.setRotation(0);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(x, y);
                parameters.setPictureSize(x, y);
                orientation = 0;
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Orientação: " + orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                parameters.setRotation(90);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(y, x);
                parameters.setPictureSize(y, x);
                orientation = 90;
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Orientação: " + orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                parameters.setRotation(180);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(x, y);
                parameters.setPictureSize(x, y);
                orientation = 180;
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Orientação: " + orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        //O SurfaceView tem sido criado, agora comunica-se com a câmera para desenhar o Preview.
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Log.e("ERRO", ex.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.cameraErro), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.cameraErro), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //Abre a câmera
    if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        openCamera();
    }
}

//...
```