# Aplicação não cria arquivo na memória externa

Tags: java, android, itext

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdftest);
        Button Btgerar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gerarpdf);
        Btgerar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CriarPDF();
            }
        });
    }
    public void CriarPDF() {
        String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PDF/" + "Ficha.pdf";
        EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        // Create New Blank Document
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        // Create Directory in External Storage
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/PDF");
        myDir.mkdirs();

        // Create Pdf Writer for Writting into New Created Document
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

        // Open Document for Writting into document
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph(txt.getText().toString()));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Close Document after writting all content
        document.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "PDF File is Created. Location : " + FILE,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Create new Page in PDF
        document.newPage();


    }
}
```

E também já declarei no Android Manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

- versão build gradle :
- compileSdkVersion 24
- buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
- minSdkVersion 8
- targetSdkVersion 24

O programa roda normalmente no meu cel, mas após geração do arquivo pdf não consigo encontrar em nenhum lugar.

Comment: Tem dois `e.printStackTrace();`, veja se algo foi escrito no *StackTrace*.

Comment: já verifiquei, mas isso é gerado pelo próprio programa

Comment: Não está la nada referente a `FileNotFoundException` ou `DocumentException`? O que fez para poder dizer "não consigo encontrar em nenhum lugar"?

Comment: tipo o app roda normalmente, mas quando clico em gerar pdf, e depois vou nos meus arquivos, no SD, e não encontro nada

Comment: tava pesquisando, será que não é algo relacionado a android permission?
tipo fala no site developer.android (Cuidado: atualmente, os aplicativos podem ler o armazenamento externo sem precisar de permissão especial. No entanto, isso será alterado em lançamentos futuros. Se seu aplicativo precisar ler o armazenamento externo (mas não gravar nele), será necessário declarar a permissão READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Para garantir que o aplicativo continue a funcionar adequadamente, declare essa permissão agora antes que as mudanças entrem em vigor.)

Comment: Você já tem lá a permissão(pelo menos até à versão 5.1). Qual é a versão do Android do seu cel.?

Comment: meu android é 6.01

Comment: tem como mudar getExternalStorageDirectory()
para getExternalFilesDir() ?? tem diferença??

Comment: É falta de permissão. Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541)

Comment: Tbm to achando que é falta de permissão, mas como faço para permitir?

Comment: Poderia me ajudar a implementar o código? 
eu mudo Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS para Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: Sim, isso é uma coisa a fazer. Note que a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541) apenas indica o que tem de fazer, para implementar você tem de perceber o que cada parte faz.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, obrigado!