# Problema conexão com Banco de dados

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Fiz um programa pra tentar conectar em um banco de dados hospedado. Porém está ocorrendo um erro :

> 08-30 10:42:13.088 1710-1710/genus.qrcodefinal E/log_tag: Error in http connection java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Parte da conexão :

```
Button botaoconecta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoconecta);
    botaoconecta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("linkdosite**");


                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="genus.qrcodefinal">



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: A app é para correr no Android 6? Ou melhor a targetVersion é API23 ou superior?

Comment: Em qualquer Android 4.1.1 +

Comment: Mas a *targetSdkVersion* é API23 ou superior?

Comment: Se for o que eu estou pensando ta na API 24, no meu programa, sou meio iniciante no assunto..

Comment: Reverti a sua edição para que a minha resposta não fique sem sentido.

Answer (score 0):

O erro deve-se a falta de permissões.

Elas têm de ser declaradas no arquivo *AndroidManifest.xml* dentro da tag `<manifest>`, mas você está a colocá-las dentro da tag `<application>`.

Altere o *AndroidManifest.xml* assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="genus.qrcodefinal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Se o `targetSdkVersion` for 23 ou superior, terá de obter essas permissões em tempo de execução.

Veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541) como fazê-lo.

Se não quiser lidar com as permissões em tempo de execução altere a `targetSdkVersion` para 22. A aplicação continuará a poder correr em dispositivos com Android 6 ou superior, no entanto em modo de compatibilidade.

Comment: Mudei a target pra 21, e coloquei o código que você citou, e continua do mesmo jeito.. Editei a pergunta pra você ver se eu fiz certo..

Comment: Continua a dar o mesmo erro?

Comment: Sim, o mesmo erro...

Comment: Se alterou `targetSdkVersion` para 21 não vejo razão para continuar a dar erro.