# Abrir o mapa na posição atual do usuário

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou tentando abrir o GoogleMaps na posição atual do usuário, já pesquisei bastante e ainda não consegui fazer funcionar no meu projeto.
Estou usando Fragments para gerenciar os layout.
No projeto atual o mapa já abre sem problemas, porém, não como citado acima.
Vou colocar os códigos aqui, se alguém puder ajudar ficarei grato!

1. Minha MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);


   //Add os ícones na Tab
   TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_selector));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_selector));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_selector));
   tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

   // Configura o ViewPager
   final CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   if (viewPager != null) {
       viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false); //Desativa a mudança de tela deslizando o dedo
   }
   final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
           (getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
   tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

       }
   });
      }

   }
   ```
2. Class MapaActivity

   ```
     public class MapaActivity extends MainActivity1 {

     @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       //Adiciona o fragment no layout da activity
       MapaFragment mapaFragment = new MapaFragment();
       mapaFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragLayout,
               mapaFragment).commit();
   }
   }

   }
   ```

   3.Layout da class MapaActivity

   ```
     <LinearLayout
     xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     map:cameraZoom="13"
     map:mapType="normal">


     <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mapa"

     ></FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
   ```

   4.Class MapaFragment

   ```
    public class MapaFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    //Objeto que controla o Google Maps
    private GoogleMap map;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa,container,false);
   //Recupera o fragment que está no layout
   //Utiliza o GetChildFragmentManager() pois é um fragmento dentro de 
   outro
      SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
           getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
   //Inicia o Google Maps dentro do fragment
   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

   return view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
   //O método onMapReady(map) é chamado quando a inicialização do mapa estiver OK.
   this.map = map;

   //Tipo de Mapa;
   map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
   }
   }
   ```

   5.Layout class MapaFragment

   ```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.ruan.goapp.Fragments.MapaFragment">

   <fragment android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

   6.Estou usando uma tab inferior

   ```
   public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
   private boolean enabled;

   public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   this.enabled = true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   if (enabled)
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   else
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   return enabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
   }

   public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
   this.enabled = enabled;
   }

   public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
   return enabled;
   }
   }
   ```

   7.Layout custom_tab

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="12dp">

   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/icon"
   android:layout_width="24dp"
   android:layout_height="24dp"
   android:scaleType="centerInside" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textSize="12sp"
   tools:text="Recents" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   8.No PagerAdapter está a lógica para a troca de telas

   ```
   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

   private Context context;
   private String[] abas = new String[]{"MAPA", "F1", "F2","F3", "F4"};

   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
   super(fm);
   this.context= c;
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {

   Fragment fragment = null;

   switch (position) {
       case 0:
           fragment = new MapaFragment();
           break;
       case 1:
           fragment = new Fragment1();
           break;
       case 2:
           fragment = new Fragment2();
           break;
       case 3:
           fragment = new Fragment3();
           break;
       case 4:
           fragment = new Fragment4();
           break;
   }
   return fragment;
   }


   @Override
    public int getCount() {
   return abas.length;
   }
   }
   ```

   9.Meu AndroidManifest

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.ruan.goapp">

   <uses-feature
   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
   android:required="true" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="@string/API_KEY" />

   <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity1">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:name=".Activity.MapaActivity"></activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
   ```

   [image: Print da tela inicial no momento]

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro tem de obter a localização do usuário, usando o FusedLocationProviderClient. Veja como nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541).

O segundo passo é usar o método `moveCamera()`, [normalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277569/2541) no método `onMapReady()`, para posicionar o mapa nessa localização:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(minhaLocalizacao, 3));
```

`minhaLocalizacao` é um objecto do tipo LatLng que representa a localização do usuário. O valor `3` é o valor do zoom em que o mapa será apresentado, pode ser outro valor.

Exemplo básico de implementação numa Activity:

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    protected Location mLastKnowLocation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //Obtém o FusedLocationClient e tenta obter a última localização conhecida
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        obtainLastKnowLocation();

        //Obtém o SupportMapFragment e pede para ser notificado quando o mapa estiver disponível
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //Se a localização já foi calculada
        //coloca uma marca e faz zoom
        if(mLastKnowLocation != null){
            zoomMapToMyLocation();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void obtainLastKnowLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                            //obtém a última localização conhecida
                            mLastKnowLocation = task.getResult();
                            //Se o mapa está disponível
                            //coloca uma marca e faz zoom
                            if(mMap != null){
                                zoomMapToMyLocation();
                            }

                        } else {

                            //Não há localização conhecida ou houve uma excepção
                            //A excepção pode ser obtida com task.getException()
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, 
                                    "Não há localização conhecida ou houve uma excepção", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    //Adiciona uma marca na última localização conhecida
    //e move a camara para essa localização com nível 8 de zoom
    private void zoomMapToMyLocation() {
        LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(mLastKnowLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnowLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lastLocation)
                                          .title("My last location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLocation, 8));

    }
}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Notas:

- Necessita `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` no *AndroidManifest.xml* e eventualmente tratar a [permissão em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541).
- Pode dar-se o caso de não haver "última localização conhecida", principalmente no uso de um emulador. Nessa situação, execute primeiro uma aplicação que use a sua localização, como o Google Maps.
  Para evitar esta situação deve usar um LocationRequest em conjunto com o FusedLocationClient, utilizando o método `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates()`([Monitorização da localização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541)).

Comment: Eu já tinha lido essa resposta, mas não consegui implementar os códigos nesse projeto. Em qual clase eu implemento o FusedLocationProviderClient ou tenho que criar uma só pra isso? Na Monitorização da localização(Location updates), eu tenho que colocar na minha ActivityMain também ou na Activity do Mapa?

Comment: Depende de onde necessita dessa informação. Se for só no mapa coloque no MapFragment. Se necessitar dela na Activity e no mapa, coloque-a no fragment e informe a Activity, chamando um método dela, sempre que a localização alterar. Se necessitar dela em mais de uma Activity o melhor, talvez, será usar um serviço.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estou pegando a posição dessa forma.

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGPS);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Lembrando que tem que usar as permisões para usar o gps.