# Google Maps retornando Latitude e Longitude como zero e problemas ao colocar o Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou tentando usar o Google Maps, e *settar* uma localização nele (puxando a Latitude e Longitude do usuário). Ele puxa e exibe num Toast, mas ele não *setta* isso no método onMapReady e nem no Marker, e se eu colocar um Log no onResume(), ele mostra como zero.

```
public class LocationHomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements MvpView, OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Title";

    private static final int PERM_LOCAL = 2;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double[] pos;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
        LocationHomeFragment fragment = new LocationHomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_localizacao_home);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    //  AQUI ELE PUXA COMO ZERO PARA AMBOS
        pos = mostraPosicao();
        Log.i("LOG", "onResume(): Lat -> " + pos[0]);
        Log.i("LOG", "onResume(): Lng -> " + pos[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            //  permisao aceita
            mostraPosicao();
            Log.i("LOG", "Aceitou");
            CommonUtils.toast(getContext(), "Aceitou");
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "Recusou");
            CommonUtils.toast(getContext(), "Recusou");
        }

        if (requestCode == PERM_LOCAL) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mostraPosicao();
            } else {
                Log.i("LOG", "else1");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "else2");
        }
    }

    public double[] mostraPosicao() {
        double[] d = new double[2];
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERM_LOCAL);
        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        d[0] = location.getLatitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("LOG", "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
                        d[1] = location.getLongitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("LOG", "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
                    } else {
                        Log.i("LOG", "Localização vindo nula");
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Log.i("LOG", "MapReady");

        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                LatLng posicao = new LatLng(-23.6179537, -46.688076);
                Log.i("LOG", "Lat: " + pos[0]);
                Log.i("LOG", "Lng: " + pos[1]);
//                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicao, 13));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(posicao)
                        .title("Local")
                        .snippet("Endereço do local")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bigpin)));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicao, 13));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema que você tem ai é que tanto o método `onSuccess(Location location)` e o `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` são assíncronos, ou seja, `onSuccess` pode ser executado antes do `onMapReady` ou o contrário.
Quando você executa `pos = mostraPosicao();` no `onResume`, a variável `pos` vai apontar para a mesma referencia que a variável `d`, que é um array de duas posições vazio. Por que ele é vazio? Porque o `onSuccess(Location location)` é assíncrono e não foi chamado ainda. Por isso que os Logs do `onResume` vão printar 0.

Uma solução é:

```
public class LocationHomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements MvpView, OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Title";

    private static final int PERM_LOCAL = 2;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double[] pos;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
        LocationHomeFragment fragment = new LocationHomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    //  AQUI ELE PUXA COMO ZERO PARA AMBOS
        pos = mostraPosicao();
        Log.i("LOG", "onResume(): Lat -> " + pos[0]);
        Log.i("LOG", "onResume(): Lng -> " + pos[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            //  permisao aceita
            mostraPosicao();

            Log.i("LOG", "Aceitou");
            CommonUtils.toast(getContext(), "Aceitou");
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "Recusou");
            CommonUtils.toast(getContext(), "Recusou");
        }

        if (requestCode == PERM_LOCAL) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mostraPosicao();
            } else {
                Log.i("LOG", "else1");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "else2");
        }
    }

    public double[] mostraPosicao() {
        double[] d = new double[2];
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERM_LOCAL);
        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        d[0] = location.getLatitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("LOG", "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
                        d[1] = location.getLongitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("LOG", "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
                        pos = d;
                        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_localizacao_home);
                        if (mapFragment != null) {
                            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("LOG", "Localização vindo nula");
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Log.i("LOG", "MapReady");

        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                LatLng posicao = new LatLng(-23.6179537, -46.688076);
                Log.i("LOG", "Lat: " + pos[0]);
                Log.i("LOG", "Lng: " + pos[1]);
//                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicao, 13));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(posicao)
                        .title("Local")
                        .snippet("Endereço do local")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bigpin)));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicao, 13));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

O que eu fiz foi mover a chamada

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_localizacao_home);

if (mapFragment != null) {
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

para dentro do méotodo `onSucess(Location location)`.

Recomendo que refatore esse código!

Abs.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A acção de adicionar o Marker ao mapa só é válida/possível após o mapa estar pronto(`onMapReady()`) e a localização ter ser obtida(`onSuccess()`).

Como, tanto a criação do mapa e a obtenção da localização, são procedimentos assíncronos não se sabe qual a ordem em que eles são terminados.

Para garantir que ambos estão disponíveis ao adicionar o Marker ele deverá ser adicionado ou no método `onMapReady()`, se a localização já tiver sido obtida, ou no método `onSuccess()`, se o mapa já estiver pronto.

Declare um atributo para guardar a localização:

```
Location myLocation;
```

Escreva um método para adicionar o Marker:

```
private void addMyPositionMarker(Location location){

    LatLng posicao = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(posicao)
            .title("Local")
            .snippet("Endereço do local")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bigpin)));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicao, 13));
}
```

No método `onSuccess()` guarde a localização obtida e chame o método `addMyPositionMarker()`, caso o mapa já esteja disponível:

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

    myLocation = location;
    if(mMap != null){
        addMyPositionMarker(location);
    }
});
```

No método `onMapReady()` chame  o método `addMyPositionMarker()`, caso a localização já esteja disponível:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.i("LOG", "MapReady");
    if(myLocation != null){
        addMyPositionMarker(myLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu testei, mas de qualquer forma ele puxa como 0 tanto Latitude como Longitude, e ao permitir, ele ainda automaticamente não move a câmera para o local indicado

Comment: Pode dar-se o caso de não haver "última localização conhecida", principalmente no uso de um emulador. Nessa situação, execute primeiro uma aplicação que use a sua localização, como o Google Maps.
Para evitar esta situação deve usar um LocationRequest em conjunto com o FusedLocationClient, utilizando o método `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates()`. Por outro lado o seu código está muito "confuso" e o problema pode estar "escondido" por causa disso.

Comment: Maravilha... Vou tentar. Mas de qualquer forma, muito obrigado!