# Que permissões necessitam ser pedidas em tempo de execução?

Tags: android, android-permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Essas são as minhas permissões, eu estou com duvida se eu preciso notificar o usuário para permitir ou não, eu estava vendo que a partir da API 23 é preciso fazer isso 
Se eu precisar, como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As permissões que necessitam de ser pedidas em tempo de execução são aquelas consideradas como "perigosas"[(Dangerous permissions)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions?hl=pt-br#nveis-de-permisso).

Dentro da lista que apresentou, READ_CALENDAR e WRITE_CALENDAR estão no grupo das "perigosas".

Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541) para saber como lidar com elas.

Comment: Você sabe me dizer em quais momentos eu devo usar o READ_CALENDAR ou WRITE_CALENDAR? Eu estou usando por precaução, pois uso o Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: As permissões READ_CALENDAR e WRITE_CALENDAR apenas são necessárias quando se pretende aceder/modificar os dados do calendário do usuário. A classe Calendar nada tem haver com isso, ela serve para manipular "instantes no tempo", logo, não necessita dessas permissões.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! Agora entendi perfeitamente!

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! Agora entendi perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código para pedir as permissões a partir da versão 23:

```
String [] permissions = {"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE", "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW","android.permission.CAMERA"};
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    int requestCode = 200;
    requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
}
```

Na variavel permissions eu coloquei algumas permissões aleatorias, altere e coloque as que vc precisar